# Unable to click the "Next" button in web scraping using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from a website https://skills.education.nsw.gov.au/nsw-fee-free to gather information on courses and their providers. My goal is to traverse each course, access the list of providers, and if there are multiple pages of providers, click the "Next" button to scrape all providers. I'm facing difficulty clicking the "Next" button on the provider's page.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import csv
import time

def extract_provider_data(driver):
    provider_names = []

    while True:
        try:
            providers = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.provider-name a"))
            )
            for provider in providers:
                provider_names.append(provider.text)
            
            # Ensure the next page button is clickable before attempting to click
            next_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.paginationjs-page.J-paginationjs-page:not(.paginationjs-current) a'))
            )
            if next_page:
                next_page.click()
                time.sleep(3)
            else:
                break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error while clicking the next page button: {str(e)}")
            break

    return provider_names

def extract_data(driver):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    data = []

    course_name = soup.find('div', class_='course-name')
    course_type = soup.find('div', class_='course-type', id='course-label-default')
    delivery_mode = soup.find('div', {'class': 'col data', 'data-th': 'delivery-mode'})
    industry_name = soup.find('div', class_='category-heading container industry-info').find('h2').text.strip()
    
    provider_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.provider-location a.provider-location-link'))
    )
    provider_link.click()

    provider_names = extract_provider_data(driver)
    driver.back()
    time.sleep(3)  # Allow time for the page to reload

    for provider in provider_names:
        row = {
            'Industry': industry_name,
            'Course Name': course_name.text.strip(),
            'Course Type': course_type.text.strip(),
            'Delivery Mode': delivery_mode.text.strip(),
            'Provider Name': provider
        }
        data.append(row)

    return data

# Extract list of URLs using requests and BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://skills.education.nsw.gov.au/nsw-fee-free'
response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

a_tags = soup.find_all('a', class_='industry')
industry_urls = [tag['href'] for tag in a_tags]

# Set up the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Ensure chromedriver is in your PATH or provide the path explicitly

# List to store all scraped data
all_data = []

# Counter for courses
course_counter = 0

# Visit each URL and extract data
for industry_url in industry_urls:
    driver.get(industry_url)
    time.sleep(3)  # Allow time for the page to load
    page_data = extract_data(driver)
    all_data.extend(page_data)
    course_counter += 1

    if course_counter >= 10:  # Limit to the first 10 courses
        break

# Close the browser when done
driver.quit()

# Save the data to CSV
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Industry', 'Course Name', 'Course Type', 'Delivery Mode', 'Provider Name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for row in all_data:
        writer.writerow(row)

print('Data has been successfully saved to output.csv')
```

From my understanding, there might be some AJAX or dynamic loading that prevents my script from clicking the "Next" button, but I'm not sure.

How can I successfully click the "Next" button on the provider page? Any guidance or solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you study the site you can find something like this `href="https://skills.education.nsw.gov.au/nsw-fee-free/accommodation-hospitality-personal-services?p=3"` you can use it to get to next page like you can fetch this link from the button and open on the page directly than clicking the button, or if you do little hardwork you can recognize the pattern of how this links are build and just a loop would work, no need to fetch the link from next button.

Comment: I'm able to click the next page for the courses under each industry, but I'm stuck when I go into each course and try to scrape all providers. When there are multiple pages of providers, the next button is not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure what problem you have in your case, but it can be solved by implementing `while` loop with steps:

1. Wait for all providers to be present.
2. Store 1st provider
3. Get providers data
4. Get next button array to check for next button presense
5. If button exists - scroll to it, click on it
6. Check that 1st provider on previous page is stale (not exist)
7. If not - break

Here is an example from direct provider url. Be aware that selector can be different in your case, as far as I don't see any `div.provider-name a` on your resource.

```py
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://skills.education.nsw.gov.au/nsw-fee-free/mining"
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
action = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get(url)

provider_names = []
while True:
    providers = wait.until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".course-name"))
    )
    temp_provider = providers[0]
    for provider in providers:
        provider_names.append(provider.text)

    next_page_locators = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.pages-item-next')
    if len(next_page_locators) > 0:
        action.scroll_to_element(next_page_locators[0]).perform()
        next_page_locators[0].click()
        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(temp_provider))
    else:
        break
```

As an alternative option - as was mentioned in another answer there,
you can get last number of pagination from Next button href attribute and open link with parameter `?p=page_number` in range of got last page `?p=2`, `?p=3`, etc.